# What is the time complexity of extracting a column from a 2d array?

Tags: algorithm, search, time, time-complexity

The idea is that I wanted to just get a specific column from a 2d array, In case I have to get a row the time complexity is O(C) since it's just a read operation but in case I have to get a column I have to actually traverse all the rows if I am correct, so in case of a NxM array the time complexity will be O(M). Am I missing something? If this is correct isn't their a way to do it faster?

Comment: If you have random access to all cells, the complexity is O(R) else you have to explain what should prevent that.

Comment: Time complexity of getting a row is not constant as well, it is O(N). No way to do it faster.

Comment: If this is an array with O(1) random access, then extracting a column takes time proportional to the column length, just like extracting a row takes time proportional to the row length. A theoretical analysis is not going to tell you anything more specific than that. However, you are right to suspect that extracting a column might take longer in practice than extracting a row. Indeed, a double-loop "For every column c: For every element e in c: do something with e" will probably take longer than a double-loop "For every row r: For every element e in r: do something with e". ...

Comment: ... To understand that, consider the following metaphor: "For every book b in this library, read every page p in book b"; compared with "For every page number n, read page number n of every book". When we're done, in both cases we've read every page of every book; but it's faster to read book by book, opening every book only once, than page number by page number, opening and closing books all the time.

Comment: @Stef The equivalent is actually "read page n of every book" vs "read all pages of book p". Assuming book p has exactly as many pages as there are books in the library, this is clearly faster.